# iOS using pthread_mutexattr_t trouble

Tags: ios, multithreading, objective-c++, mute

i am porting an existing c++ project to objective-c++ and came across this mutex stuff. I am not sure what is done here neither if it is correct. To initialize some kind of multithreading lock mechanism (called "CriticalSection") the following is done:

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t cs;
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
```

Later in code:

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
pthread_mutex_init(&cs, &attr);
```

To enter the "lock" there is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&cs);
```

To leave the "lock":

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&cs);
```

My question (since I have no clue how this is done) is: Does this look like a correct implementation?
Because I encounter problems that look like the lock mechanism just does not work (bad memory access errors, corrupt pointers in situations where the "CriticalSection" was used).

Answer (score 0):

It's correct except that you don't want to destroy the mutex when unlocking. Only destroy the mutex when you can guarantee that all threads have finished with the it.

for example:

```
class CriticalSection
{
public:
    CriticalSection()
    {
        pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
        pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
    }
    ~CriticalSection() { pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex); }
    void Enter() { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); }
    void Leave() { pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); }
private:
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};
```